# Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'orgPreferences'

Tags: salesforcedx, package, unlocked-package

Suddenly, the following error message pops up when trying to build a new package using
`sfdx force:package:version:create`.

```
Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'orgPreferences' at line 1, column 353
```

This is reproducable on my Win10 and macOS machine. Also, I can rule out that this has something to do with me. It even appears when I revert to older commits on my repository where I know for certain that I was able to build packages from them.

For the sake of completeness, here's my scratch-org-def.json

```
{
  "orgName": "Partner Billing GmbH",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": ["StateAndCountryPicklist", "MultiCurrency"],
  "country": "DE",
  "language": "en_US",
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
        "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "pathAssistantSettings": {
        "pathAssistantEnabled": true
    },
    "languageSettings": {
        "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
    },
    "chatterSettings": {
        "enableChatter": true
    }
  }
}
```

Note, the non existing `orgPreferences`. Since this is for my open source project, you could reproduce this, using my latest commit: https://github.com/jlietzau/partner-billing/tree/feature/PB-67-community.

Does anybody has an idea where this comes from? My hunch is that salesforce fucked up their API that is responsible for creating package versions.

Comment: I just started getting the same thing, glad I'm not the only one. I was just about to raise a Partner Support Ticket for this

Comment: Should it help, my scratch org is far simpler. `{ "orgName": "MyCoolApp", "edition": "Developer", "hasSampleData": true, "features": [] }`

Comment: Please do and keep us in the loop :). I'm very relieved that I'm not the only one. I also started having "unexpected errors" on my other production org.

Comment: I suspect this is a bug in the CLI

Comment: I sent out a tweet as well. The more the merrier, right?

Comment: I 'think' this is due to the maintenance going on noted @ https://status.salesforce.com/current/incidents as we changed nothing as well and started getting this error today only.  our CD/CI works fine for deploying and testing to scratch orgs but as soon as it goes to our environment to test the merge against a replication of production we are getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear this error was the result of something done on the Salesforce API side. Trying again 3 hours ago, the command did execute successfully (though it took a bit longer).  Should I get any details from the support case, I'll update this.

Comment: Something mus still be up, as their commands are taking 15-20 minutes (even for a `force:package:version:list` ).